Java Spring Boot 3 Spring Security OAuth2 Unauthenticated Endpoint
I want that a specific endpoint /public/info should be available without authentication.
My application.yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: team1
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          # provider name used for registration
          demo:
            # Keycloak realm URL: "{keycloak-url}/realms/{realm-name}"
            issuer-uri: 
        registration:
          # client-id from Keycloak client configuration
          demo-client:
            # provider from above
            provider: demo
            # client-id from Keycloak client configuration
            client-id:
            client-secret:
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri:

server:
  port: 8080


My SecurityConfiguration:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
                authorize.requestMatchers("/public/info").permitAll();
                authorize.anyRequest().authenticated();}
            ).oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
   
}

Shouldnt /public/info be available unauthenticated? I always get redirected to keycloak.
The /public/info endpoint is:
@GetMapping(path = "/public/info")
public String hello() {
    return "Hello";
}

My build.gradle - maybe here could be a problem using a wrong version.
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

group = 'at.ac.fhwn'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}



What you show is correct. You must be hiding something that breaks your app.
A good question should contain:

dependencies (all of it, with versions)
configuration (all of it, with properties, a notable exception being secrets values)
DEBUG or TRACE logs showing the problem

Complete app (which works):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Configuration
  @EnableWebSecurity
  static class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
        authorize.requestMatchers("/public/info").permitAll();
        authorize.anyRequest().authenticated();
      }).oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
      return http.build();
    }

  }

  @RestController
  static class PublicController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/public/info")
    public String hello() {
      return "Hello";
    }
  }

  @RestController
  static class PrivateController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/private/info")
    public String hello(Authentication auth) {
      return "Hello %s".formatted(auth.getName());
    }
  }

}

spring:
  application:
    name: demo
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          demo:
            issuer-uri: https://oidc.c4-soft.com/auth/realms/quiz
        registration:
          demo-client:
            provider: demo
            client-id: change-me
            client-secret: change-me
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code

server:
  port: 8080

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org:
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG
        boot: INFO

And the passing integration tests showing it works as expected:
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.oauth2Login;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithAnonymousUser;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class DemoApplicationTests {
  @Autowired
  MockMvc api;

  @Test
  @WithAnonymousUser
  void givenRequestIsAnonymous_whenGetPublicInfo_thenOk() throws Exception {
    api.perform(get("/public/info")).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }

  @Test
  @WithAnonymousUser
  void givenRequestIsAnonymous_whenGetPrivateInfo_thenRedirectToLogin() throws Exception {
    api.perform(get("/private/info")).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
  }

  @Test
  void givenUserIsAuthenticated_whenGetPrivateInfo_thenOk() throws Exception {
    api.perform(get("/private/info").with(oauth2Login())).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }

}


Thanks for your answer, that was almost my complete application there were no more configs in the application.yaml. I updated my question with the build.gradle maybe there is a problem

It could be another filter-chain in Java configuration or missing @RestController on the class containing @GetMapping(path = "/public/info") or whatever I can't see in your code. As you don't seem to be ready to share a reproducible sample, you'll have to start from what I provided and incrementally modify it.
